# Deploying multiple webapps to multiple servers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a build and release pipeline on azure devops. The build works as expected and so does the release. I want to be able to release the same project to multiple IIS servers, however I don't want to copy and paste the same job. Is there a way that I can get it to deploy to several IIS servers using the same set of deployments. I have been researching and can't seem to be able to find the solution to this.

Basically I want to be able to use one release and have it used to deploy to a set of IIS servers. This is so I can avoid duplication and retain the maintainability I need.

Comment: Use task groups to create a set of reusable activities. Then the only thing you'll need to change between stages or releases is the variables you pass in.

Comment: If the IIS servers are on different machines, you can try deployment groups so that you specify a deployment group phase which publishes to agents installed on each server in parallel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops